# Thermodynamic degrees of freedom of a wire

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics

In Equilibrium thermodynamics by *C.J Adkins* he mentions an example about degrees of freedom of a thermodynamic system --

> Very often for a simple system it is possible to say immediately that how many degrees of freedom it has from a knowledge of it's properties .*For example , a wire subject to tension only has 2 degrees of freedom ,for it is known that it's length depends on tension and temperature only*

So I don't really understand that how he concludes that the wire has only two degrees of freedom **only by knowledge of the fact that it's length depends only on tension and temperature**..

Because for me there are many more thermodynamic properties of this system apart from it's length...so *how can we conclude it*.

Comment: Can you name another property that is of relevance to the length of the wire?

Comment: @lemon are you sayin that all other properties so far are totally dependent on length and temperature

Comment: In thermodynamics, you want to look at relavant degrees of freedom subject to the problem you are posed or you want to solve. Resistance could be a degree of freedom, but how can it be related tension applied on the wire. It would therefore be useful to consider when solving electrical circuit problems to use resistance as a degree of freedom with temperature.

Comment: You have it the wrong way round, @HiteshPathak. It's not that all other properties are dependent on tension and temperature, it's that the length is dependent only on tension and temperature.

Comment: @lemon yes i know that length is fixed for given values of tension and temperature

Comment: @lemon my question is that how this fact leads us to the conclusion that this tension and temperature can work as degrees of freedom for this system

Comment: And by degrees of freedom i mean the minimum no. of properties that can be used to specify state of the system

Comment: @user35952 i never mentioned resistance as a degree of freedom rather i said that it counts as anotherthermodynamic property

Comment: By degree of freedom I mean a thermodynamic degree of freedom in the thermodynamic parameter space, not in the mechanical sense ! In your case, even Tension and length are thermodynamic parameters or degrees of freedom !!

Comment: @user35952 i mean the same when i said the min. number of properties to specify state(thermodynamic state)

Comment: @user35952 i am NOT bothered about mechanical degrees of freedom

Comment: Yes, so the minimum number of properties required is only 2, tension and length (of course temperature is there, but then you have an equation of state as a constraint) to describe the mechanical properties of the wire from thermodynamics, like expansivity etc. Now if you want extract some other properties of  wire, then you will use a different set of parameters with a different equation of state.

Comment: @user35952 so all other mechanical properties of our interest are dependent on LENGTH AND TENSION....by some equations...am i right??

Comment: To a reasonable extent yes. As you yourself have stated, its the minimum required quantities. There might be other quantities like volume, pressure etc. but they will have very insignificant effect on the wire's mechanical properties.

Comment: @user35952 yes it has been assumed that the volume remains essentially a constant..you can give this as an answer . I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum number of properties required is only 2, tension and length (of course temperature is there, but then you have an equation of state as a constraint) to describe the mechanical properties of the wire from thermodynamics, like expansivity etc. There would be other mechanical parameters (pressure, volume etc.) but would have very little effect on the properties in the case of the wire.

Now if you want extract some other properties of wire (non mechanical), then you will use a different set of parameters with a different equation of state. For example, if your interested calculating some electrical properties of the wire using thermodynamics (like resistivity for instance), then you have to choose parameters that are relevant that physical situation with a different equation of state.